# Sqlplus command to change oracle database password in kornshell scipt

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am writing a script to change passwords on Oracle databases. I am successfully able to get the database name, user_id, old password, and new password. I have this command to change the old password and set it to new:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF 
connect ${USER_ID}/"${OLD_PASS}"@${DB_NAME} 
alter user ${USER_ID} identified by ${NEW_PASS} replace ${OLD_PASS};
/
exit
EOF
```

When I store the result into a variable and print out the variable, I get an error stating:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.

I believe it has to do with the alter user command. How can I fix this command so the password change is successful via my script?

Comment: Without seeing how you are setting the variables, and what their actual values are, we can only guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The variables have been tested and contain the appropriate credentials for the user and DB_NAME also contains the correct database

Comment: Apart from what Alex said about quoting the variables, You shouldn't be using a `/` after the `alter` statement. It will cause a rerun of the same statement, which will fail because now your old password is not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are enclosing the old password in double-quotes in the `connect` string, it seems likely that the old and possibly also the new passwords have special characters. The error you are getting is consistent with either password having, say, an exclamation mark; but could also start with a number, have multibyte characters, etc.

[From the documentaton](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/keeping-your-oracle-database-secure.html#GUID-451679EB-8676-47E6-82A6-DF025FD65156):

> You must enclose the following passwords in double-quotation marks:
>
> - Passwords containing multibyte characters.
> - Passwords starting with numbers or special characters and containing alphabetical characters. For example:
>
>   ```
>   "123abc"
>   "#abc"
>   "123dc$"
>   ```
> - Passwords containing any character other than alphabetical characters, numbers, and special characters. For example:
>
>   ```
>   "abc>"
>   "abc@",
>   " "
>   ```

So, enclose them in the `alter user` too:

```
alter user ${USER_ID} identified by "${NEW_PASS}" replace "${OLD_PASS}";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a part of my problem. Now when I run my script, I get: Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long. I assume that means the length of my new password is too long?

Comment: Probably, if the new password is more than 30 chars. The error message should point to the line and character  position of the issue; likely to be the first double-quote in `"${NEW_PASS}"`. (If the old one was that long the `connect` would fail first.) Again, though, if you'd included sample - representative - values in the question we wouldn't need to speculate. But:  ["Passwords can be at most 30 bytes long."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-AA1AA635-1CD5-422E-B8CA-681ED7C253CA). And note that is *bytes*, not *chars*.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out, I was getting an error if my new password has special characters but making the new password relatively simple allowed the script to work just fine

Comment: I think the only thing that doesn't work at all in a password is a double-quote character, but via the shell script I can imagine you might have an issue with a backslash depending on where it is, or an ampersand (you can `set define off for that), and possibly a dollar sign though probably not. Inside quotes anything else should be OK though I think.